# Hydrogen as a reference in inductive effect

Tags: organic-chemistry, inductive-effect

What does it mean when we say that I-effect of hydrogen is taken as zero ?

I think that it means that partial displacement of sigma bond electrons between two atoms of different electronegativity is measured with respect to hydrogen i.e.

Relative partial displacement of $\sigma$ bond electrons in polar bond =
actual partial displacement of those electrons- displacement of electrons that would happen if hydrogen was a part of bond

Is my reasoning wrong? If so, why?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_effect It is relative inductive effect where we consider hydrogen as reference.

Comment: @0.00 in that case only what does it means when we say that hydrogen is reference?